# No response from tcp/udp ports

Tags: validator

Here is my Solana validator command line:

```
solana-validator --identity ~/validator-keypair.json\
                 --vote-account ~/vote-account-keypair.json\
                 --rpc-port 8899\
                 --entrypoint entrypoint.devnet.solana.com:8001\
                 --limit-ledger-size\
                 --log -
```

And, here is the output:

```
[2022-07-06T06:58:12.614029180Z INFO  solana_net_utils] Checking that tcp ports [(8899, TcpListener { addr: 0.0.0.0:8899, fd: 87 }), (8900, TcpListener { addr: 0.0.0.0:8900, fd: 88 }), (8000, TcpListener { addr: 0.0.0.0:8000, fd: 89 })] are reachable from 35.197.53.105:8001
[2022-07-06T06:58:22.483997284Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] submitting 9 points
[2022-07-06T06:58:22.744456643Z ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8899, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
[2022-07-06T06:58:27.745117007Z ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8900, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
[2022-07-06T06:58:32.745829119Z ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8000, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
```

Note that the firewall is ok and ports are open also I used the sys-tuner before running the solana-validator command and followed the docs step by step! **Now, how to solve this port issue?**

**Hoq

Comment: I have got no answer from discord. because in my country discord is banned.

Answer (score 2):

At startup, solana-validator verifies whether all public ports necessary for Solana to work are externally reachable. It does so by asking another node to try and connect to all required ports on your node.

If you are running behind a firewall, make sure the [validator port range](https://docs.solana.com/de/running-validator/validator-reqs#port-forwarding) (by default, 8000-10000 UDP/TCP) is publicly reachable.

Running Solana behind NAT is not recommended because the Turbine block propagation mechanism won't be able to directly send blocks to your node.

Comment: default range is 8000 - **10000**

Comment: The port range is added to my firewall rules and they are publicly reachable. How can I figure out that my virtual machine is behind NAT or not?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I think that the solana validator is rejecting the TCP communications, finally did you solve the issue?